# Truffle v5.4.15 deploy error with newly create project

Tags: truffle-migration, truffle-deployment

**truffle deploy** returns with the following error, in a newly create project (using flutter init)

> ## 1_initial_migration.js
>
> ### Deploying 'Migrations'
>
> Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***
>
> "Migrations" -- Returned error: unknown account.

I believed it is caused by my settings at **truffle-config.js**.

```
development: {
  host: "localhost",
  port: 8545,
  from: "0x60fDF758ed3549D550A52f2044B43aadf782aA4E",
  gas: "8500000",
  gasPrice: "50000000000",
  network_id: "*" // Match any network id
}
```

I have stopped programming in solidity for 6 months, and didn't aware there are so many changes :(

Answer (score 0):

truffle by default uses the first account from ganache network, why do you need to specify the from address? if its necessary make sure the account is in ganache's network.

here is my suggestion

```
 development: {
     host: "127.0.0.1",     // Localhost (default: none)
     port: 8545,            // Standard Ethereum port (default: none)
     network_id: "*",       // Any network (default: none)
    },
```

Comment: I have create 10 accounts in my **Genesis.json alloc** section. And that **from** address is the last one in the alloc list. These accounts are used for my regression test. And I am still getting the same error after removing the from.

Comment: this might help   https://medium.com/blockchainbistro/set-up-a-private-ethereum-blockchain-and-deploy-your-first-solidity-smart-contract-on-the-caa8334c343d

Comment: thanks. I just realized that I cannot simply use any address in the alloc list without importing that account using private key (and I have been using that for the past 1 year). This is actually a loophole which had been fixed. Otherwise we can deploy any contract using any arbitrary account with balance.

Comment: understood! glad it worked!